# Generating webservice client classes using wsimport

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee

I am trying to understand how to create web services, as I am new to them.
I am going through the following tutorial:

http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example/

I have a question, and needs a bit of explanation.
When we create Java Web Service Client via wsimport tool, it creates two files, HelloWorld.java, and HelloWorldImplService.
My question is that, we all ready have HelloWorld.java interface that we have created when creating the web service(the first interface that we create at the top of the tutorial), and now there is another HelloWorld.java interface, how does the two files get distinguished?

regards Harbir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generating the client side code from the WSDL indeed also generates the HelloWorld interface. In practice, when you create a web service client, all you have is the WSDL. You don't have the server side source code, as usually the server is run by some third party. That is why this interface is generated when you generate client side code, but also when you generate server side code.
But if you happen to own both the server side code and the client side code then you can consider putting the common source files in one shared module and eliminate duplicates.